# Is there a model, apart from Random Forest, which uses bagging?

Tags: sampling, random-forest, bagging

What are the popular machine learning algorithms which make use of bagging? Are there any apart from random forest?

Comment: The wikipedia article has an example using LOESS regression. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating

Answer (score 2):

Random forest is a readymade algorithm where bagging is applied/ integrated into the model. But, can be used in any regression models or we can write own codes to use bagging technique along with any machine learning models to be implemented.